# Flutter - How to fix RenderFlex overflowed error?

Tags: flutter, layout

I want to make a list view with image background. this is my builder code

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: this.locations.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(this.locations[index].url),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(this.locations[index].name,
                  style: Styles.listItemStyle)
            ],
          ));
    },
  )
```

[image: some of the text is being clipped]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: the problem can be seen in the screenshot. You have the overflow marker there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the issue comes from the names, the text is bigger than the screen and therefore Flutter is trying to render something that will not be seen. There are some solutions you can consider:

- Use the [auto_size_text package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text), it will automatically shrink the text font size to fit its constraints.
- Use the [LayoutBuilder widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get the text's parent `constraints` and force the text to fit within its available size with a `SizeBox`, then you can set `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` in your `Text` constructor to show three dots if the text does not fit the screen.
- Use a horizontal [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to make the text scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a row when your container only contains one Widget? Try removing the Row widget. Then the text inside Container should break right?